# WinSCP: Find option lists all folders

Tags: winscp

I am using WinSCP for navigating all my unix (virtual) machines.

When I use the "find"-dialog to search for specific file names and try to use a simple mask "status.dat". Why does it list all my directories?

It's miraculous...

Do you have ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can depend on the exact version of the WinSCP you are using:

[Bug 840](http://winscp.net/tracker/840) has been fixed in 5.0.7, and was about:

> When finding files, all directories are implicitly found